# .addClass specificity with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I set my div's background color in css. When I click on the div, I want to change it's background color by adding another css selector. Regardless of how I arrange the selectors in my css file, the background color will not change to red. Is there anyway I can set the specificity when using `.addClass`?

Clicking on the div does change the background to red if I don't give the div the `default_color` class.

```
$('.js-div').on('click', function (e) {
  $(e.toElement).addClass('selected_color');
}

.selected_color {
 background-color:#F00;
}

.default_color {
 background-color:#0F0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are using `toElement`, change it to `this` or `e.target`

```
$(this).addClass('selected_color');
```

or

```
$(e.target).addClass('selected_color');
```

And CSS order will matter when the specificity is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the event listener you should reference the clicked element with $(this), and you dont need to use on, you can use click. It's important to change the order of classes in ypur CSS, so selected_color override default_color

```
.default_color {
 background-color:#0F0;
}

.selected_color {
 background-color:#F00;
}

$('.js-div').click(function () {
  $(this).addClass('selected_color');
}
```

If you want to toggle color with click you can use

```
$('.js-div').click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected_color');
}
```

Working example with toggle http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdPezK

Comment: There are better ways than setting `!important` statement as e.g adding more specificity in CSS rule or regarding cascading order

Answer (score 0):

You could just toggle a class like so:

```
$('.js-div').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('colorify');
});
```

CSS:

```
.js-div {
    background: #0f0;
}

.js-div.colorify {
    background: #f00;
}
```

This is a common pattern of having the default element have a specific color or whatever, and then just toggle a class that changes it (instead of having two individual classes).

If you do need two different classes for whatever reason, you can toggle the second class, or just call `removeClass` for the first and `addClass` for the second, but this is more to keep track of.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `.selected_color` is on top of `.default_color`. Since styles cascade, I am assuming `.default_color` is overriding the rule above it. Try switching them.

```
.default_color {
  background-color:#0F0;
}

.selected_color {
  background-color:#F00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read up on how CSS works... If you put one definition below another, then the second one will overwrite the first one. In your case it should be enough to switch positions between `.selected_color` and `.default_color`.

Then there is the case where a more precise selector in CSS overrides a more broad selector. So `a` will be overridden by `a.class_name` and `a.class_name` will be overridden by `p > a.class_name`.

[This article explains it a bit better.](http://codeumbra.eu/the-cascade-part-of-css)

Answer (score 0):

Using your CSS this jquery will accomplish the desired effect on the click and revert back to the original state if click again. If you do not want the ability for it to revert back simply leave out the `else if` statement:

```
$('.js-div').click(function(){
        if ($('.js-div').hasClass('default_color')){$('.js-div').removeClass('default_color').addClass('selected_color');}
        else if ($('.js-div').hasClass('selected_color')){$('.js-div').removeClass('selected_color').addClass('default_color');}
    }
```